# Curve on a torus

Tags: geometry, 3d, curves

Consider a curve $f$ that connects two arbitrary points on a torus. What are the equations that defines the curve $f_{min}$ whose such a distance is minimal?

Comment: This may help http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf

Comment: Also, the torus is a surface of revolution which means that you can apply Clairaut's relation. This way you can find geodesics on the torus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends  strongly on the metric you choose in the torus  $T$.

Since $T$ is uniformized by the plane $\Bbb R^2$ a canonical metric on $T$ is the flat metric with constant curvature 0. For this the geodesic arcs are image of line segments in the plane.